# React-Native: SecureStore works on mobile. How to keep JWT secure on Web browser?

Tags: react-native, jwt

`SecureStore` does **not** work on Web, so I do this:

```
async function getUserDetails() {      
    try { //Android and Apple 
        const token = await SecureStore.getItemAsync('token')
        const data = await axios.get(apiurl+'&JWT='+token)
        console.log('using SecureStore')

    } catch (err) { //Web
        const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token')
        const data = await axios.get(apiurl+'&JWT='+token)
        console.log('using AsyncStorage')
    }
}
```

So if I want to attack my own app, I just use the browser, and i'll be able to see the JWT in plain text right? How to tackle this?

Answer (score 0):

React Native mostly use on `ios` and `android` but if you want to use this application on web you can encrypt those data using [`Crypto`](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/crypto/) so you encrypt your data before you store them.